# Wordpress like meta_query can i filter post by post_title?

Tags: wordpress

I need to modify or create a WP_Query that will search for a search term in both the post title OR a custom field (called 'my_field').

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the Codex documentation for using [WP_Query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Search_Parameter) with a search parameter?